# Know When Child Form Closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a Form1 with a button. When you click the button, this code block executes:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Name = "Form" + musteriNumarasi.ToString();
frm.Text = "Kullanıcı - " + musteriNumarasi.ToString();
```

Lets say I've clicked three times. There are four forms now: Main, Child1, Child2, Child3. When user closes one of the child forms, main form needs to know which one is closed. How can I do that?

Comment: One way is to have the parent listen for their child's form closed event.

Comment: Either establish a listener on the parent form for the child's close event or, less semantically, in the child's close event you can execute code on your main form.

Comment: Subscribe the FormClosed event.  Either use a dedicated event handler for each specific child or a common one, the *sender* argument tells you which one was closed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Closed Event`

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();    
frm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form_Closed);

void Form_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = (Form2)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(frm.Name);
}
```

Comment: This gives a compile error. 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler'

Comment: Then change FormClosedEventArgs to EventArgs

Answer (score 3):

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();   

frm.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.frm_FormClosed);
```

.
.
.

```
private void frm_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Runs after closing child :)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

add these lines to your code to handle the event of closed Or Closing Form

```
frm.Closing += Form_Closing;
frm.Closed += Form_Closed;
```

add the following Methods to the current Class

```
void Form_Closing (object sender,EventArgs e){
//Handler form Closing Event
}
void Form_Closed (object sender,EventArgs e){
//Handler form Closed Event
}
```

Comment: `sender` will be the reference on the Form object that triggered the event

Comment: You should really edit your answer instead of using comments.

Comment: this comment is only a tip to help you with my answer.